# Where should i add css in html file?

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I was trying to add css in my blogger's blog but for some reason blogger theme designer is not working so i decided to add css directly in the code using  tags, but I can't find the  tag in the html file. It is my first time when I am unable to understand where  is. Anyone know where  tag is in this file to add css?
I did not Code it completely! And the person who did is no longer in contact with me!

[Click Here to see Code](https://justpaste.it/3qnyk)

Comment: Inside the head tag using a link tag

Comment: That is the problem! I cant find the head tag. There is this code in the file: &lt;/head&gt;&lt;!--<head/>--&gt;

but i can't find <head>*******</head>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for this `]]></b:skin>` and place your CSS code before it without using `<style>`

Or if you want to use a style tag, place it after `</b:skin>`

Comment: I tried! But it is not showing up in the live site. And I also noticed that the css code that I had added in Blogger theme designer is above  ]]></b:skin>  but it is not taking affect! Do you by any chance know why it is not working?

Comment: ]]></b:skin>
<style>
body {background-color:black;}
</style>

tried this but it does not show up.

Comment: Try to add your style before this `&lt;/head&gt;&lt;!--<head/>--&gt;`

Comment: i have attached the code file in the question as a link can you take a look?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/14HZOo6hIyHeHsamIwB0e2Dk4PMcQabRrvXxCatY7NhM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, you can add your style element before this line `&lt;/head&gt;&lt;!--<head/>--&gt;`

Comment: thank you! it works. But do you know why Blogger theme editor is not working? I know there is some problem in the code.

Comment: Because of your template uses amp

Comment: And use style from tags like `<style amp-custom='amp-custom'>` Comes after <b:sken> tag so it override the CSS

Comment: so there is nothing i can do to use Blogger theme editor while using amp?

Comment: You can use it but it should come after the amp tag. try change its place after amp tags but back up your template first.

Comment: tried but i can't seems to figure out where to place which amp tag :(

Comment: Move `<b:skin> ..... </b:skin>` before head closing tag `&lt;/head&gt;&lt;!--<head/>--&gt;`

Comment: Or before javascript before this line `<script async='async' src='https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js'/>` to avoid rendering late

Comment: It worked! Both of them worked! so where should i place it for better optimization? before head closing tag Or before javascript ?

Comment: I prefer before JavaScript tag to load faster.

Answer (score 2):

To use an external style sheet, add a link to it in the  section of the HTML page:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: That is the problem! I cant find the head tag. There is this code in the file: &lt;/head&gt;&lt;!--<head/>--&gt; but i can't find <head>*******</head>
take a look at the code attached!

Comment: Make sure to put the head at the top of a web page. The head should contain meta data such as author, title etc.

Comment: &lt; stands for lesser than (<) symbol and, the &gt; sign stands for greater than (>). That is the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

The `<style>` element is used to add CSS style rules to an HTML document. The element is expected to appear in the document `<head>`, but will also render acceptably when used in the `<body>` of the document.

Comment: I know but HTML5 now a days recommend using CSS <style> element in <head> and not in <body>, as it could be problematic in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

you should add the head tag yourself to the top of the document if you do not have one already. for the href change that to the name of your css file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML amp='amp' lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
<!--[if ie]><meta content='IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE; chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/> <![endif]-->
<meta content='blogger' name='generator'/>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
<link href='https://justpaste.it/redirect/3qnyk/http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g' rel='nofollow'/>
<link expr:href='' rel='nofollow'/>
<link expr:href='' rel='nofollow'/>
</head>
```

Comment: But will it not break the code if I add a head tag and there already exists a head?